# How does bindView() method works in Android SimpleCursorAdapterClass

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I am new to Android. I implemented a ListView scrollable application by following a tutorial. But I can't understand how is bindView() method in SimpleCursorAdapter class worked when scrolling the list.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (holder == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.colImp = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.COL_IMPORTANT);
        holder.listTab = view.findViewById(R.id.row_tab);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    if (cursor.getInt(holder.colImp) > 0) {
        holder.listTab.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    } else {
        holder.listTab.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    //store the column index
    int colImp;
    //store the view
    View listTab;
}
```

Comment: any why you tag the `View` with the `ViewHolder`? see this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter); maybe it helps understanding it better. your `ViewHolder` doesn't even have a constructor (I'd assume in the IDE some of it might be in red).

Comment: yes @MartinZeitler, I added only the relevant part to bindView() method. My actual question is, how does affect the ViewHolder object behavior to the ListView. I can't find any path that is connected to ListView and ViewHolder object?